# Javascript: start Lottie animation when is in viewport

Tags: javascript

I have simple Javascript code where I'm trying to make a script where Lottie animation may start when is in the viewport.

Now, this is not working.

Is there any solution to how I can start Lottie animation when is in the viewport?

Lottie animation has id **jancovic** and when is this element in viewport Lottie animation may start.

Already all is in if a statement is not changeable can't be the change I need to change only if the statement probably.

```js
var jancovic = document.getElementById('jancovic');
var boundingJancovic = jancovic.getBoundingClientRect();
    
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (boundingJancovic.top >= 0 && boundingJancovic.left >= 0 && boundingJancovic.right <= window.innerWidth && boundingJancovic.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
    
        var svgContainerJancovic = document.getElementById('jancovic');
        var animItemJancovic = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
            wrapper: svgContainerJancovic,
            animType: 'svg',
            loop: false,
            path: '/assets/anim/graphs/data.json'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `bodymovin`?

Comment: Already what is in if is static the if I need to change.

Comment: You need an event listener that listens on scroll events. Then you can calculate the current viewport and compare it with the position of your object. That can't be solved with a simple `if`

Comment: already I edited it can you look at it because it is not working too:(

Comment: Variables like `boundingJancovic.top` won't change. The element doesn't move. The viewport changes. You have to read the borders of the viewport. `window.onscroll` is called with a parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd62q749/)

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking for the same thing. took me a good 30min plus
(and a coffee) to get this working, so i hope this helps anyone

```
<script>
// kickstat the animation - mine is a div with the id of "headerAnimation"
// which sits inside a div with an id of "header"
var headerAnimation = lottie.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById("headerAnimation"), // the dom element that will contain the animation
    renderer: "svg",
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    path: "SOME_PATH_TO_FILE" // the path to the animation json
});


// "listen" & check when header is out of viewport 
// (i set 50% = visible => threshold: 0.5 (to set))
const headerViewport = function() {
    let options = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 0.5
    }

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
        entries[0].isIntersecting === true ? headerAnimation.play() : headerAnimation.goToAndStop(0, 0);
    }, options);

    observer.observe(document.querySelector('#header'));
}

// on window load
window.onload = function() {
    headerViewport();
}
</script>
```

**btw**
as far as i can see, its "lottie.loadAnination" and not bodymovin
i think that, that's the old way of writing it.

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted my lottie animation to behave, you really saved me time - thanks!

Comment: How would you go about if there were more animations on the same page? I've tried
calling it three times, changed all the IDs to match, all three animations are loaded but only the last one reacts on viewport in and out.

Comment: i have a slightly different example i created to answer another question (I wanted to animate all the items that have a specific class when in viewport) - you can find a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/sagive/xzhmfvt5/9/ - does this help?